# WINSRV | Unable to remove Remote Desktop Service Web Access (0x800f0922)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services, uninstall, iis-8.5

I have a big problem, because I can't uninstall the Remote Desktop Service Web Access role. I am always getting error code 0x800f0922.
When I want to uninstall it with IIS, my server restarts and says service error - reverting.
I have already deleted all SSL Cert bindings, however this server is a Domain Controller and I think this is the main problem. I don't know how I installed RDS, but now i really need to remove it, because my IIS install is corrupted.
The server is running Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter.